# Python HashTable implementation quicker than list iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, big-o

This is a [problem from HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/). My implementation as shown below passes most of the test but for the tests that it fails, it states that it is taken too long. After looking at other submissions, I found that another user's implementation (credit to [saikiran9194](https://www.hackerrank.com/profile/saikiran9194)) passes all tests almost immediately. I really am having trouble understanding why his solution is the most efficient at scale.

**My Implementation:**

```
m, n = map(int, input().strip().split(' '))
magazine = input().strip().split(' ')
ransom = input().strip().split(' ')
yesNo = "Yes"
for i in ransom:
    if(ransom.count(i) > magazine.count(i)):
        yesNo = "No"
print(yesNo)
```

**More Time Efficient Implementation**

```
def ransom_note(magazine, ransom):
    rc = {} # dict of word: count of that word in the note
    for word in ransom:
        if word not in rc:
            rc[word] = 0
        rc[word] += 1

    for word in magazine:
        if word in rc:
            rc[word] -= 1
            if rc[word] == 0:
                del rc[word]
                if not rc:
                    return True
    return False

m, n = map(int, input().strip().split(' '))
magazine = input().strip().split(' ')
ransom = input().strip().split(' ')
answer = ransom_note(magazine, ransom)
if(answer):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: add a break after yesNo = "No"?

Comment: I thought of that as well. This change passes more tests, but still not all of them. Any thoughts as to why the other implementation is quicker?

Comment: `count` is linear, so your code has quadratic complexity. By putting it in a dict first, it only needs O(1) to get the count for a certain letter.

Comment: Ah, makes perfect sense...Thank you so much!

Comment: Hash table iteration is not necessarily faster but hash table lookup is `O(1)` whereas each call to `list.count()` is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the difference between `list.count` and `dict.__getitem__` (`rc[word]`). `list.count` is `O(n)` whereas `dict.__getitem__` is `O(1)` due to, as you mention, hashing.

Source: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 1):

`list.count` has linear complexity, so your code has quadratic complexity overall, doing linear work in each iteration of the loop. By putting the lists in a `dict` first, it only needs O(1) to get the count for a certain letter.

You can just wrap those lists into [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (not tested):

```
m, n = map(int, input().strip().split())
magazine = Counter(input().strip().split())
ransom = Counter(input().strip().split())
yesNo = "Yes"
for i in ransom:
    if(ransom[i] > magazine[i]):
        yesNo = "No"
print(yesNo)
```

Or shorter using `any`

```
yesno = "No" if any(random[i] > magazine[i] for i in ransom) else "Yes"
```